# Why do we blow on the “hurricane balls” only after they begin spinning?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, home-experiment

In the [hurricane balls](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=hurricane+balls) phenomenon, we have 2 balls welded together and by spinning them first by hand on the smooth tabletop, we are then able to accelerate it by blowing a through a nozzle at the balls.

However, my query lies as to why the blowing of the balls via he nozzle has to be done after the hand spinning, and not before.

My current speculation is that the spinning of the balls grants it centripetal force, but I’m not very sure how I can answer my problem with that premise.

Comment: According to my understanding, only one of the balls remains in contact with the surface, which can only happen when they are already spinning sufficiently fast enough. The balls therefore behave like a turbine when you blow on them.